# counting individual elements that meet a certain criteria without duplicates in sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to count all the individual actors from movies in 2004 the problem is when I tried using the count() function it returned how much times every actor appeared in a movie that year.
basically I cant get count() to play well with the GROUP BY function.

```
SELECT COUNT(name) FROM people
INNER JOIN stars ON stars.person_id = people.id
INNER JOIN movies ON stars.movie_id = movies.id 
WHERE movies.year = 2004 
GROUP BY name;
```

relevant tables: movies (id, title, year), stars (movie_id, person_id), people (id, name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to count the number of `DISTINCT` `person_id` in `stars` (no need to use the `people` table at all) that have been in movies made in 2004:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT person_id) AS num_actors
FROM stars
JOIN movies ON movies.id = stars.movie_id
WHERE movies.year = 2004
```

Comment: I needed the people table bc that's what I had to do for a cs50 problem set but you saved me the time of manually counting 18000+ lines to see if I had the right answer

Comment: @CodeForX fair enough - anyway, I'm glad this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are not specifying the field you intent to be used for aggregation.Query will return name of actors and respective count of movies. Try below,

```
SELECT name,COUNT(*) FROM people
INNER JOIN stars ON stars.person_id = people.id
INNER JOIN movies ON stars.movie_id = movies.id 
WHERE movies.year = 2004 
GROUP BY name;
```